# I want to use a custom option radio button to show/hide other options

Tags: magento-1.9, php, custom-options

I am trying to show or hide certain custom options depending if a radio button option is set one way or the other.
I am trying to follow this guide but I can't make it work.
[Dynamically Hide Custom Options in Magento](https://www.apharmony.com/software-sagacity/2014/10/dynamically-hide-custom-options-in-magento/)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!